# Unable to Get additional fields to show on Profile update page using django

Tags: python, html, django-forms

I am having a problem with getting some additional fields to show up on the website. I want to have the viewer be able to add their phone_number and their birth_date but the form that I created is not showing up. If anyone could give me some direction, been trying this for 3 days.

#### Code

`.view.py`

```
def Profile(request):
args = {'user': request.user}
return render(request, 'index/profile.html', {})


def update_profile(request, user_id):
user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
user.save()

class ProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
user_form = UserForm
profile_form = ProfileForm
template_name = 'profile.html'

def post(self, request):

    post_data = request.POST or None

    user_form = UserForm(post_data, instance=request.user)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(post_data, instance=request.user.profile)

    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user_form.save()
        profile_form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Your profile was successfully updated!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('profile'))

    context = self.get_context_data(
                                    user_form=user_form,
                                    profile_form=profile_form
                                )

    return self.render_to_response(context)

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

`.model.py`

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
phone_number = models.IntegerField(default="", editable=True)
birth_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

`.form.py`

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
    widgets = {
        'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    }


class UserUpdateForm(UserForm, UserChangeForm):
first_name = forms.CharField(
    required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
)
last_name = forms.CharField(
    required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
)
email = forms.EmailField(
    required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
)


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ('phone_number', 'birth_date')
    widgets = {
        'phone_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'birth_date': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    }


class ProfileUpdateForm(ProfileForm, UserChangeForm):
phone_number = forms.IntegerField(
    required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
)
birth_date = forms.CharField(
    required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
```

`.profile.html`

```
{% block body %}
<h2>{{ user.get_full_name }}</h2>
<p>Username: {{ user.username }}</p>
<p>Phone Number: {{ user.profile.phone_number }}</p>
<p>Birth Date: {{ user.profile.birth_date }}</p>

<div class="container">
<form method="post">
    {{user_form.as_p}}
    {{profile_form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<br>
</div>
```

**`OR`**,

```
<form method="post">
{{ user_form.as_p }}
{{ profile_form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

There is no place to enter the `phone_number` and `birth_date`

[image: image pointing the problems]

Answer (score 0):

Took a 2 day break and came back to this issue.

The main issue was that I was trying to do too much and made it overly complex. Easy is the answer.